# Searching solution for generating smart URLs

Tags: php, mysql, api, frameworks

I have a page with lots of articles in different categories.

For this page I want to generate smart urls related to an article by using my own keyword list. The related keywords (about ten of them) are viewed below the article as "smart-links" (such as: keyword = travel -> http:// mydomain.org/travel).

In case of a view keywords and articles that wouldn't be a problem. I would just get my keywords and articles from the database (MYSQL) and regex them until I have my ten matches, but for this project I have about 100 000 keywords and about the same number of articles. I can't even load the keywords into my php script without exceeding my php script's memory limit.

For that reason I need a good solution that doesn't get the server to surrender.

Any suggestions from frameworks over design patterns to brilliant MYSQL queries are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you need to show 100 000 keywords on one page?

Comment: No, I have this keywords in my database and want to show about 10 of them in the article view (if they are related to the current article). So the main issue is to search the most related keywords out of my keyword list.

Comment: If I got you correctly, you want to show related links on a page. Do you have an index of your articles, indexed by keywords or fulltext?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. At the end of my script the user that clicked on the article needs to see the maximum 10 links, below the article, such as <a href="http://mydomain.com/keyword>.

The title of each article and the first n characters of the articles text are indexed by mysql in my database.

Comment: But how do you know which are the most related keyword? Or is that what you're asking?

Comment: Exactly, that and the fact that I don't even know how I find the keywords that are related at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a list of all words in the article filtering them by certain criteria, for example longer then 2 letters, excluding common words such as "after", "because", etc. Put them in an array with the number of their occurrences. Sort descending by the number of occurrences. After that check each word top down to see if it matches a keyword in your database. If it does, show it as a link. Stop after you've got ten of them.